# Typescript same namespace multiple files

Tags: typescript

I'm just picking up on Typescript and I have a lot of code that I want to separate in multiple files using the same namespace: `ProjectName.Validators`. This namespace will hold a part of my project which handles some validations.

The validation package is composed of an `interface`, an `exception` class and the validator classes (email, regex, url etc..). Some of the validator classes are quite long and I would really like to split each one on it's own separate file. My ideal project structure would be as follows:

```
project/
    validators/
        interface.ts
        exception.ts
        email.ts
        url.ts
        regex.ts
        ..... extra classes in ProjectName.validators namespace
    main.ts
```

The problem is that my interface has one of the methods accepting as a return a `void` or my custom exception being thrown and I can't seem to link that exception in the code since the ts compiler is complaining about the fact that the `Module ... has no exported member 'Exception'` since the exception is under the same namespace in a different file.

Here's my interface definition (simplified):

```
/// <reference path="./exception.ts"/>

export module ProjectName.Validators {
    // Interface for all validators (builtin or custom)
    export interface Interface {
        validate(params?: Object): void|ProjectName.Validators.Exception|Error;// this is where I get the error
    }
}
```

and also my exception definition:

```
export module ProjectName.Validators {
    export class Exception extends Error {
        public name: string;
        public stack: string;

        constructor(public message?: string){
            super(message);
        }

        toString() {
            return this.name + ': ' + this.message;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I tried playing with the export keyword a lot with no success. What am I doing wrong?